# XPath with multiple child node conditions

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to find a XPath expression, to get an elment with multiple conditions on child nodes.

Which XPath can I use to get the ball element with *ART_NR* = 146334 and *FABRICATOR* = SPALDING?

The corresponding XML:

```
<xml>   
    <ball sellCode="ABC7001" type="basket ball">
         <detail>
            <type>INFO</type>
            <values>
               <type>NUMERIC</type>
               <value>146334</value>
               <id>ART_NR</id>
            </values>
            <values>
               <type>NUMERIC</type>
               <value>39.99</value>
               <id>PRICE</id>
            </values>
            <values>
               <type>STRING</type>
               <value>SPALDING</value>
               <id>FABRICATOR</id>
            </values>
            <values>
          </detail>
          <detail>
             <type>MOD</type>
             ...
          </detail>
    </ball>
    <ball sellCode="ABC34564" type="golf ball">
    ...
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the following XPath expressions should work:

```
/xml/ball[detail[values[id='ART_NR'][value=146334]]
                [values[id='FABRICATOR'][value='SPALDING']]]

/xml/ball[detail[values[id='ART_NR' and value=146334]
             and values[id='FABRICATOR' and value='SPALDING']]]
```